# .asp file replaced on production but the codes changes are not reflecting

Tags: asp-classic

I have changed the code in the .asp files and sent the files for deployment to replace the two asp files and sysadmin confirmed that he has replaced the files.
but when i checked the page same old functionally is reflecting.
could you please tell the troubleshooting steps to solve this issue? I don't have the access to production and I have coordinate with the sys admin team.

Comment: Have you asked the admin, what he did?

Comment: he  confirmed that replaced the files that I have sent in the relevant path.

Comment: web page in cache? try to reset cache in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you haven't restarted your server.
try to restart IIS server and again check.

Answer (score 0):

web page in cache? try to reset cache in your web browser.

if you don't have access to production server and you cannot guarantee than sysadmin really put new files on web server, put something like this in your ASP files:

```
<%
  Response.Write "THIS IS REVISION #1 from 09/Jun/2015" 
%>
```